# How to determine memory allocation for single level table

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I received this problem on my study guide but I have no idea if I'm doing it correctly:

**How much space needs to be allocated for a single-level page table for a machine with a 32 bit virtual memory address and a 4K page size?**

I understand that the last 12 bits of the address is the offset but how would I determine how much space is needed?